# Elseif statement does not execute

Tags: php, if-statement, search, echo, concrete5

I'm trying to display the `$attributevalue` of a productpage from the Concrete5 Community store in a search block, hide if empty en diplay a other value if the result is not a product page. All works fine, except when the attribute of a productpage is empty. What It want to display is: "no attribute data". It now shows the list whitout the data.

I'm no programmer and don't know were it goes wrong. Does is has something to do with the result beeing NULL or 0?

```
<?php
   $product = \Concrete\Package\CommunityStore\Src\CommunityStore\Product\Product::getByCollectionID($r->getCollectionID());
   if ($product && (strlen(trim($attributevalue)) >= 0)){ 
   $attributevalue = $product->getAttribute('artikelnummer');?>
      <ul class="searchlist">
         <li><span>Artikel nr.:</span> <?php echo $attributevalue ; ?></li>
      </ul>
   <?php } 
   elseif ($product && (strlen(trim($attributevalue)) == 0)){
      echo 'no attribute data';
   } 
   else {
      echo 'no productpage';
   }
?>
```

Comment: Remove the = operator, you cannot have a zero and a bigger than zero length in strlen(trim($attributevalue)) >= 0) to add a value to $attributevalue.

Comment: If above solution does not work, try to cast the `$attributeValue` first into a string (like `trim((string) $attributeValue)`) before trimming.

Comment: Removing the = operator did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because `if($product && (strlen(trim($attributevalue)) >= 0))` by this you are strictly checking both the variables `$product` and `$attributevalue` that they are `>=` to `0` or not

**Change your if statement to**

```
if(isset($product) && strlen(trim($attributevalue)) >= 0)
{
...
}
```

Comment: The `&&` separates both statements and the `>=` is only for the second. This means your solution does not solve the problem.

Comment: yes it sure seprates the statements but by conditionally it forces both to be >=0